# If I pull a url with automatic redirects from a .json, how can I make the output the page that I would have been redirected to? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

The urls in question are not from my own website.

This code uses discord.js and is for a bot to pull the url of a post from reddits .json. It doesn't work with nsfw gfycat links as they are now all automatically redirected to their new location in the gifdeliverynetwork.

```
    if(cmd == `${prefix}r`){
    if(message.channel.nsfw){
        request("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + args + "/top/.json?t=all&limit=100", function(error, response, body){
            let msg = JSON.parse(body);
                try{
                    let imgurl = msg["data"]["children"][Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 0)]["data"]["url"];
                    if (imgurl.includes('gfycat')) {
                        return message.channel.send(imgurl + "\nr **" + args + "** requested by **" + message.author.tag + "**" + "\n***can't see the post?** - discord doesn't support most gfycat links but you can still click it!*");
                    } else {
                        return message.channel.send(imgurl + "\nr **" + args + "** requested by **" + message.author.tag + "**");}}                        
                catch{
                    return message.channel.send("Error getting data from the subreddit - **" + args + "**");
                }
            });
    } else {
        return message.channel.send("This channel is not set to nsfw. Please use <rp");
    }
}
```

Comment: What module are you using for `request()`?

Comment: @Brad 'npm install request' I think